i have an error that eslintreact/require-default-props with eslint-plugin-react
HI i have a project with react typescript and eslint(eslint-plugin-react/airbnb ...).
i have an error that propType "accoTriggerClass" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration.eslintreact/require-default-props from below code.
function AccordionDemo({
  accordionData,
  chevronDirection,
  accoTriggerClass = "",
  accoItemClass = "",
  accoContentClass = "",
}: {
  accordionData: { title: string; content: string }[];
  chevronDirection: "left" | "right";
  accoTriggerClass?: string;
  accoItemClass?: string;
  accoContentClass?: string;
}) {
  return ( 
... 

so i solved this problem adding a code
AccordionDemo.defaultProps = {         accoTriggerClass: "",         accoItemClass: "",         accoContentClass: "",  }
but i noticed a message that Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.     at AccordionDemo in console.
so i don't want to use defaultProps, but i don't know fallback on that.
somebody help me..!

defaultProps is deprecated and going to be removed.  You should do both of the following:

Go ahead and entirely remove AccordionDemo.defaultProps = { ... } from your code.
Turn off the react/require-default-props ESLint rule. How to do this depends on how you've configured eslint, but common places to set it are tsconfig.json, eslintrc, or inline (e.g. // eslint-disable-next-line eslintreact/require-default-props)

Read more about this deprecation at: https://sophiabits.com/blog/stop-using-defaultprops
